# Is there a way to make phonegap apps more secure?

Tags: security, cordova

I have created an app for android using phonegap, but I am worried about how secure the code I wrote is going to be... It seems like it would be fairly easy to copy the code and build another app off of it... How would I make it more secure? I have been searching around and couldn't yet find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might like to refer to http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/43660891/Security

Or do you want to make your app closed source???

Comment: @Areke: I hope you know it will cost you.                           As for costs, the "PhoneGap Build service will always be free for open source projects". This implies closed source will probably have to pay a usage or license fee.

Comment: Oh, I am not using PhoneGap Build... I have set up Eclipse and have my application running on my own android device. I just found that the full html and javascript source code can be found in the www file and want to know if it is possible to hide the www file.

Comment: I just obfuscated it as best as I can, thanks for your help! If you figure anything out, please let me know!